# Is it true that java.lang.Class object is created when the Java class is loaded, even before instantiation takes place?

Tags: java, reflection, static, jvm, instantiation

Suppose the classes has code like this:

```
class C {
    public static void show() {
    }
}

class CTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        C.show();
    }
}
```

Then will it be perfectly legal to conclude that while referring to class `C` to access the static method `show()` here, behind the scene Java is actually calling the `show()` method through Java reflection ?

I.e. is it actually doing something like this

```
Class test = Class.forName(C);
test.show();
```

to call static methods?

If not, then how is it actually calling the static methods without creating objects?

If the above explanation is true, then how we'll justify the statement that "static members are only associated with classes, not objects" when we're actually invoking the method through a `java.lang.Class` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The JVM doesn't need to do anything like `Class.forName()` when calling a static method, because when the class that is *calling* the method is initialized (or when the method runs the first time, depending on where the static method call is), those other classes are looked up and a reference to the static method code is installed into the pool of data associated with that calling class. But at some point during that initialization, yes, the equivalent of `Class.forName()` is performed to find the other class.
2. This is a specious semantic argument. You could just as easily say that this reinforces the standard line that a static method is associated with the *class* rather than any instance of the class.

Comment: You're welcome to add your own answer, or make suggestions to improve this one.

Comment: I see what you're saying in point 1, but it's a little hard to understand. Point 2 is spot on though. +1.

Comment: IMHO this is somewhat misleading. The called class will get loaded when it's first referenced by calling code. Not really when the calling class gets initialised, or when the method runs. These imply (to me) that the called class is loaded because it's referenced somewhere inside the calling class or method. The JVM only resolves and loads the class at the specific line of code that it first needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM divides the memory it can use into different parts: one part where classes are stored, and one for the objects. (I think there might have been third part, but I am not quite sure about that right now).

Anyways, when an object is created, java looks up the corresponding class (like a blueprint) and creates a copy of it -> voila, we have an object. When a static method is called, the method of the class in the first part of the memory is executed, and not that of an object in the second part. (so there is no need to instantiate an object).

Besides, reflection needs a lot of resources, so using it to call static methods would considerably impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

For extra info:

The called class will get loaded when it's first referenced by calling code.
i.e. The JVM only resolves and loads the class at the specific line of code that it first needs it.
You can verify this by using the JVM arg "-verbose:class" and stepping through with a debugger.

It will call ClassLoader.loadClass(String name) to load the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a println statement into the ctor, to verify, whether it is called or not:

```
class C {
    public static void show () {
        System.out.println ("static: C.show ();");
    }

    public C () {
        System.out.println ("C.ctor ();");
    }

    public void view () {
        System.out.println ("c.view ();");
    }

}

public class CTest
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println ("static: ");
            C.show ();
        System.out.println ("object: ");
            C c = new C ();
            c.view ();
            c.show (); // bad style, should be avoided
    }
}
```